# how to make if (message.content.startsWith('')) detect for 2 things

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

So I have the code

```
if (message.content.startsWith(''))
```

in my script and I want it to make it so it goes through if it is uppercase OR lowercase. I tried

```
if(message.content.startsWith('>command', '>COMMAND'))
```

but that didn't work. Can someone tell me the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with RegExp `^>command`(where `^` is [start anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)) and [flag `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) for ignoring case.

```
if(/^>command/i.test(message.content)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value to lowercase first before matching

```
message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(">command")
```

You can use search

```
message.content.seach(/^>command/i)
```